# Como buscar markers já criados num mapa - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Tenho um mapa onde já existem carregados uma série de Markers. Nesse mapa preciso de ir buscar todos os markers, e mostrar uma listagem com os markers visíveis ao utilizador, para fazer uma pequena listagem de dados à semelhança deste [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/glafarge/mbuLw/).

Como é que consigo carregar para uma variável javascript todos os markers criados no mapa?

Ps.- Estou a trabalhar em outsystems, e não me dão a possibilidade de instalar API's terceiras para além do Google Maps.

Comment: Não sou especialista no google-maps @CesarMiguel, mas já utilizei o [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/?hl=pt-br) do maps para obter informações detalhadas de uma determinada localização.

Comment: @LucasCosta estou a trabalhar em outsystems, não me dão a possibilidade de usar outras API's para além do google maps. Obrigado na mesma

Comment: A places API é da Google e usada junto com a Google Maps, usam a mesma base de dados..

Comment: Posta seu códigio que monta o Mapa aí.

Comment: Que listagem se refere, aos pinos aparecerem no mapa? Já conseguiste inserir os markers no mapa?

Comment: @Gumball o mapa é criado por um componente outsystems, onde envio apenas as moradas e o componente cria os markers respetivos

Comment: @Miguel os pinos são os markers. Sim, o mapa já tem os pinos, só quero mesmo ir buscar-los em javascript

Comment: Ha ok, percebo mas como estás a inseri-los? Já não tens a localização desde o príncipio? Ou vêm do lado cliente dinamicamente?

Comment: @Miguel, foi como disse ao Gumball. Estou a inserir os markers a partir de um componente da Outysystems, onde só envio a morada e faz tudo sozinho. Basicamente agora quero buscar todos os markers já criados num mapa em javascript. É como se fosse já um mapa com markers vindo do lado do cliente

Comment: Ok então se percebi bem, tens de pôr aí um ajax para mandar o todos os markers para o servidor e guardas num ficheiro ou numa base de dados... Se só quisres as coordenadas de cada um, um ficheiro é o suficente guardando as coordenadas de cada marker por linha

Answer (score 2):

Tente fazer assim:

```
var Bounds  = osGoogleMap.OSMaps.DublinTheme_wt106_block_wtMainContent_Google_Maps_wtMap_block.getBounds();
var Markers = [];

for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
   if(Bounds.contains(markers[i].position))
      Markers.push(markers[i].title);
}

console.log(Markers);
```

Comment: O map tem de ter obrigatoriamente um Bound criado?  `map.getBounds('BoundTeste').contains(map.getMarker(i).gMarker.position)` dá erro: contains is not a function

Comment: Cara, seria bom ver seu código. Não tem como postar ? Se foi um Mapa criado pela API do Google, é pra ter o `getBounds`. Posta o código que você está fazendo, por favor. Assim fica mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: deixo exemplo de como em outsystems tenho de verificar se um marker existe no mapa (não estando a fazer para todos os markers): `osGoogleMap.OSMaps.DublinTheme_wt106_block_wtMainContent_Google_Maps_wtMap_block.getBounds().contains(osGoogleMap.OSMaps.DublinTheme_wt106_block_wtMainContent_Google_Maps_wtMap_block.getMarker("DublinTheme_wt106_block_wtMainContent_Google_Maps_wtMap_block_319d74db-37cf-4940-b497-b120f3539420").gMarker.getPosition())`

Comment: Ok, então e como vou buscar os `markers`? Uso `osGoogleMap.OSMaps.DublinTheme_wt106_block_wtMainContent_Google_Maps_wtMap_block.markers`?

Comment: Cara, está dentro do `For`. Ele vai percorrer as instâncias do Bounds e pegar todos os markers. Não é isso o que você quer ? Você leu o código ?

Comment: Li... mas estás a instanciar o markers no `For`, correto? Ele tem de ser inicializado em algum lado

Comment: Como assim que lado ? É só colocar os markers dentro de um array e você já tem todos eles.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50440/discussion-between-cesarmiguel-and-gumball).